# Match element to part of a data attribute value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a piece of code which targets an element that does not have a matching value in a data attribute. If I click a button, all elements that don't have a matching value in this attribute will show.

For example:

```
<div data-the-vals="Female_Young.Dev,Male_Mid.Project"></div>
```

then in my jquery I'm trying to access 'data-the-vals' to see if ANY of these values exist, like so:

```
$('div.professions:not([data-the-vals="' + myElementVal + '"])');
```

where myElementVal could equate to 'Female_Young.Dev', OR 'Male_Mid.Project'.

In the console I'm getting back the following:

```
$('div.professions:not([data-the-vals="Female_Young.Dev"])');
```

which is what I want but it seems to be unable to find this div as it's finding "Female_Young.Dev,Male_Mid.Project" instead of the first part of the value I want. Is it possible to split this up, or be able to search the data-the-vals attribute to see if it exists in some capacity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So use [attribute contains](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) instead of equals.

```
$('div.professions:not([data-the-vals*="Female_Young.Dev"])');
```

Comment: ...THANK YOU! Of course it was an incredibly simple oversight. I will mark this as the accepted answer!