# Selecting an image element by using the source attribute to find it

Tags: javascript, html, dom, tampermonkey

I'm working on a script for a website, and I need to change the icon of one of its images. The problem is the image on the site only has a tag like this:

```html
<img src="/pic1.png" alt="clear" >
```

I have tried selecting the image by using:

```html
document.querySelector("img[src='pic1.png']");
```

What I have tried looks like this:

```
var y = document.querySelector("img[src='/pic1.png]'");
y.innerHTML = "<img src='pic2.png' alt='clear'>";
```

I also tried

```
var y = document.querySelector("img[src='/pic1.png]'");
y.src = "/pic2.png";
```

Is there anyway I can find the image using the `src` attribute, assign it to a variable, then replace the `src`?

Your help is appreciated :)

Comment: I apologize for the edits, there where a few editing errors I had to rectify.

Comment: `document.querySelector("img[src='/pic1.png]'");`  should be `document.querySelector("img[src='/pic1.png']");`

Comment: Voting to close as typo

Comment: I apologize, my editor didn't recognize the error. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your last example should work

```
var y = document.querySelector("img[src='/pic1.png']");
y.src = "/pic2.png";
y.load()
```

Comment: The src attribute is much longer in reality, could that be why its not finding it?

Comment: @VeneerLarry Yes. You should use the answer(s) to [Match element to part of a data attribute value?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50349539/215552) in that case.

Comment: You where right the first time, I just had a typo in my code thanks to Cuong Le Ngoc for pointing it out.

Answer (score -2):

How about you set an Id on that element, then select it using document.getElementById(), then you can proceed to access the src property, which can help you change its value.

Comment: I'm making a script for that website, so I cannot alter the existing code on the site.

Comment: The solution to all "I need to find an element in the DOM" questions is not "put an ID on it". Please adjust your answering strategy accordingly.